# Black borders when overlaying a transparent texture over another in fragment shader

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

My scene consists of a plane which I'm shading with two textures. The first, bottom-most, texture is a solid image coming from the camera of the iPhone, the second image is a kind of viewfinder which I need to  overlay over the camera input (with transparency). I'm getting these black dark lines at the borders of solids in my transparent texture.

[image: Black borders around solids]

I've been doing some research on this and came to the understanding that this artifact is a result of interpolation combined with premultiplied alpha. Since XCode converts all PNG images automatically to premultiplied pngs and the code I wrote to load the image is also respecting a premultiplied alpha context I'm kinda stuck on where the exact problem is located.

I've tried the following solutions:

- made sure that pixels with an alpha value of 0 had their rgb values also set to 0
- turned off xcode's automatic png compression so that it leaves the texture as provided by me
- fiddled around with the fragment shader to avoid the mix() call
- changed the AlphaInfo value when creating the bitmap context

Important: I'm not using glBlendFunc(), I'm feeding the two textures together to 1 fragment shader and try to mix them in there. So a solution through this gl-call won't get me any further.

Here's the code I'm using for loading the transparent texture:

```
shared_ptr<ImageData> IOSFileSystem::loadImageFile(string path, bool flip) const
{
    cout << path << endl;
    // Result
    shared_ptr<ImageData> result = shared_ptr<ImageData>();

    // Convert cpp string to nsstring
    NSString *convertedPathString = [NSString stringWithCString:path.c_str() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], convertedPathString];

    // Check if file exists
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:NO])
    {
        // Load image
        UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath] autorelease];
        CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

        // Allocate memory for the image
        size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
        size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
        GLubyte *spriteData = (GLubyte*) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));

        // Create drawing context
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

        // Flip for OpenGL coord system
        if(flip)
        {
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
        }

        // Draw & release
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height), imageRef);
        CGContextRelease(context);

        // Put result in shared ptr
        // Don't free() the spritedata because our shared pointer will take care of that
        // Since the shared pointer doesn't know how to free "calloc" data, we have to teach it how: &std::free
        shared_ptr<GLubyte> spriteDataPtr = shared_ptr<GLubyte>(spriteData, &std::free);
        result = shared_ptr<ImageData>(new ImageData(path, width, height, spriteDataPtr));
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "IOSFileSystem::loadImageFile -> File does not exist at path.\nPath: " + path;
        exit(1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here's how I set the pixels on the texture:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, 
    GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Here's a stripped down version of the fragment shader:

```
void main(void)
{
    lowp vec4 camera = texture2D(texture0, destinationTexCoord);
    lowp vec4 viewfinder = texture2D(texture1, destinationTexCoord);

    lowp vec4 result = mix(camera, viewfinder, viewfinder.a);

    gl_FragColor = result;
}
```

Comment: Totally a shot in the dark- change the Xcode `compress PNGs` build setting to NO

Comment: I already tried setting that option to NO, cleaned the target and ran again. Same black borders keep popping up.

Comment: Why are you talking about PNGs?  No GPUs use that.  Use PVRTC RGBA 4bpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem by investigating how the `glBlendFunc` call works. I used [this editor](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php) to check what formula is used to blend with `GL_ONE` and `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`.

This led to the following fragment shader code:

```
lowp vec4 camera = texture2D(texture0, destinationTexCoord);
lowp vec4 viewfinder = texture2D(texture1, destinationTexCoord);

lowp vec4 result = viewfinder + camera * vec4(1.0 - viewfinder.a);
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be because of `premultiplied alpha` in PNG images. Try to modify blending mode:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); // instead of (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

Comment: I'm not using glBlendFunc, check my post.

Comment: You are using blending with default params. Just for checking, insert this line before drawing call.

Comment: Inserted and tested but same results.